# a search word (W) in the dictionary in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to bring back the words that contains the letter 'W' in it in prolog.
I need to write a program in prolog that brings all the words that contain 'w' in it.

I have tried everything and I'm unable to figure it out.

Here is the list.

[aid, ale, ant, ape, ara, arm, art, bat, bea, bee, boa, but, dad, day, dry, ear, eat, eel, egg, end, eta,
gem, get, got, hen, ian, may, met, oat, old, our, owe, pad, pie, pig, pin, poe, pre, pro, ran, rig, row,
sam, say, sea, see, set, ted, the]

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: How much is "everything"? I recommend: [maplist/3](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3) with a goal that uses [atom_chars/2](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_chars/2) and ... and ... [memberchk/2](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=memberchk/2). _"Muskatnuss, Herr Mueller!"_

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried everything

Yeah right ;-)

Forget about atom_chars/2 and memberchk/2. You want sub_atom/5:

```
?- List = [aid, ale, ant, ape, ara, arm, art, bat, bea, bee, boa, but, dad, day, dry, ear, eat, eel, egg, end, eta, gem, get, got, hen, ian, may, met, oat, old, our, owe, pad, pie, pig, pin, poe, pre, pro, ran, rig, row, sam, say, sea, see, set, ted, the],
    member(X, List),
    once(sub_atom(X, _, _, _, w)).
```